# Import modules and unimport them all

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, contextmanager, python-importlib

My task now is to develop (write) a module that should do the following:

1. Load (dynamically import) libraries in the main program using the "newly-written" module. I don’t know which libraries they will be in advance (I will receive them in the form of a list, .txt file, etc.)
2. Execute specific business logic using these libraries
3. Return to the main program, after cleaning the cache (imported libraries)

Now I have done it pretty simple:
I have a context manager that wraps the code that loads libraries and works with them. The context manager "remembers" what libs was before and after leaving. Then it tries to return everything as it was before its launch.

Context manager:

```
@contextmanager
def path_and_modules_keeper(libs_path: Path) -> None:
    old_sys_modules = sys.modules.copy()
    old_sys_path = sys.path[:]
    sys.path.insert(0, libs_path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.path = old_sys_path
        current_sys_modules = sys.modules.copy()
        for key in current_sys_modules.keys():
            if old_sys_modules.get(key) is None:
                del sys.modules[key]
```

How to use cont. manager:

```
def do_business_logic(libs_path: Path)
    with path_and_modules_keeper(libs_path) -> Any:
        ...
        load_libs(libs_path)
        result = some_business_logic()
        ...
        return result
```

Comment: Why do you need to "un-import" the modules? Is there a particular problem when you don't do it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, there is. 
For instance, let's say that I imported `lib_a` which dependency is `lib_z==2.5`
Now I need to import `lib_b` which dependency is `lib_z==1.7`
So in this case I won't be able to load `lib_z==1.7` 'cause `lib_z==2.5` is already in `sys.modules`.   
Cosequently `lib_b` won't work correctly